# Can .NET Ria service push data from server to client?

Tags: .net, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services

Can the .NET RIA Service automatically push data to the silverlight client without the client polling the server at all?

I want a feature similiar to wcf duplex polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently. It's something they are thinking about for version2 apparently.

You can do it with WCF: [.WCF Duplex with Silverlight](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/18912.aspx)