# Can .NET Ria service push data from server to client?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659062/can-net-ria-service-push-data-from-server-to-client) has been asked previously for Silverlight 3.0 but now that Silverlight 4 is out and Silverlight 5 is on the horizon, is it possible to push data from server to client with RIA services yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet. You can watch the [Wish List](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/57026-wcf-ria-services) for updates.